# Matlab smoothing

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

How can apply  user-defined mask as a vector e.g. [1 1 1].

```
img=imread('xxx.jpg');
mask=[1,1,1];
f=conv2(img,mask);
```

"Undefined function 'conv2' for input arguments of type 'double' and attributes 'full 3d real'."

Answer (score 1):

Color images are 3 dimensional arrays (x,y,color).  conv2 is only defined for 2-dimensions, so it won't work directly on a 3-dimensional array.

You can use an n-dimensional convolution, convn() instead of conv2(). Another possibility is to take each color separately and do a conv2()

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can i convert my image 2-dimensionals?.

Comment: Thank you it work well, but now my masked photos seems only changed too  much, i want to make only smoother at a vector. do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply a mask to your image you can try to use the following example:

```
                Im2 =rgb2gray (fr);                   
                fr=Im2.*uint8(mask);
```